# Three theorems for Polyhedra, Polytopes, and Cones

Tags: polyhedra, polytopes

Are there readable proofs of the following theorems?

1. A polytope (bounded polyhedron) is the convex hull of a finite set of points.
2. A polyhedral cone is generated by a finite set of vectors. That is for any $m \times n$ matrix $A$, there exists a finite set $X$ such that
   $\{x=\sum\lambda_ix_i, x_i\in X, \lambda_i\ge 0\}=\{x: Ax\le 0\}$.
3. A polyhedron $P:\{x: Ax\le b\}$ can be written as the Minkowski sum of a polytope $Q$ and a cone $C$
   $\left(\text{i.e.}, P=Q+C=\{x+y, x\in Q, y\in C\}\right)$.

I was wondering if someone could show me any proof of one of three above theorems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of

> Ziegler, Günter M. *Lectures on Polytopes*. Vol. 152. Springer Science & Business Media, 1995. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-8431-1).)

whose first chapter is on basic properties: Polytopes, Polyhedra, and Cones.
Theorem 1.1 on p.29 is your #1.
Theorem 1.3 on p.30 is your #2.

---

[image: GunterCover]

---